# Based on mat-tree checkbox selection, filter table in angular6

Tags: json, checkbox, filter, angular6, angular-material-6

I am using this for group checkbox in angular 6.
https://stackblitz.com/angular/nkmjydodvnp?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts

Here suppose I have a JSON data like this:

```
     "data": [
          {
            "reminderName": "Cook dinner",
            "status": "some value",
          },
          {
            "reminderName": "Read the Material Design spec",
             "status": "some value1",

          }
]
```

And I am displaying this data in a table.
So here I want is, whenever I will select "Cook dinner", only cook dinner related rows should filter from table, or if I will select both "Cook dinner" and "Read the Material Design spec", then these two row only should show from table.

Can anyone please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
    $(function() {

   $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.data, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.reminderName+ "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.status+ "</td>" 
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#jsondata tbody");
     });

   });
});
</script>

<div>
   <table id= "jsondata" border="2">
  <thead>
            <th>Reminder Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
```

HERE !!! PLEASE COMMENT BACK IF IT HAS ERROR

Comment: yes try it. in angular material just dont forget the 
<script>
...........
</script>

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the selected checkbox value here. https://stackblitz.com/angular/nkmjydodvnp?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts